# Overlay network in docker swarm not working

Tags: nginx, networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

This is my setup: https://github.com/czpo/docker-reverse-proxy

So there is a simple nginx/php stack called "site1" on the worker, and when I put a reverse proxy on the worker node it will load that site in the browser.

But if I put the RP on a manager (like in the repo) I get a:

> host not found in upstream error 502

even though I have an overlay network that connects the RP with Nginx/php?